# How can I add a sup number to a TextView programmatically?

Tags: java, android, textview, rows, android-tablelayout

How can I put that little number in the same column (textView) or how can I add two of them .
I have tried linearlayout horizantal but it did not worked How I want that text view to be look like;
 [ı want to add number like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHEMc.png)

```
        //this my textView for adding to rows        
        txtColumnArray[i] = new TextView(this);
        txtColumnArray[i].setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        txtColumnArray[i].setAllCaps(true);
        txtColumnArray[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        txtColumnArray[i].setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        txtColumnArray[i].setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20f);

       // my last try is spanable but it is not working , I thought it may be 
      // coz of textView properties but couldnt find it.

        spanableForQuestionNumbers[questionNumbersCount] = new SpannableString(questionNumbersCount + " " + LetterFormat[count]);
        spanableForQuestionNumbers[questionNumbersCount].setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        txtColumnArray[i].setText(spanableForQuestionNumbers[questionNumbersCount]);
        trCrosswordRow.addView(txtColumnArray[i]);
```

Comment: Can you share the code that you have implemented till now.

Comment: have you ever tried with constraint layout? this should be simple

Comment: No I haven't ,Isnt this gonna make everything a bit more complicated , Btw I want to make it dynamically